# Error 407 with proxy enabled using Endian Firewall

Tags: firewall, proxy, authentication, endian-firewall

I need to navigate on a web and enter user and a password. This is done from a PC with Windows 7.

When I have the proxy of my Endian Firewall (hosted on another PC on my network) disabled from my Windows PC everything is ok.

But when I enable the proxy, that has by default all the webs denegated and only you can to access to the DNS that I enable, I add the exception of this DNS but I get the error 407 "Proxy Authentication Required."

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Do a test with a website that does not require the authentication, I think you'll still have the authentication required error because it's the Endian that is asking the authentication not the final website.
In this case you've to disable the authentication otherwise the question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

This article may help you to understand your http error code :

> https://httpstatuses.com/407

Also did you inspect the all the http header with the Dev tools for Chrome for example?!